# UITableView displaying data weirdly swift 3.0

Tags: uitableview, swift3, ios10

Issue: [image of UITableViewCells that never display data without being selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz937.png)

The issue is consistent enough that even disabling User Touch Interactions still caused this issue to appear. The rows should have 3 sub-rows, but just the end of that section was displayed (along with the title, as displayed in the image).

The code for this table view:

```
import UIKit

class HistoryViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

    var data = LocalizedData.localizedData
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "tableCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
        //tableview.allowsSelection = true
        tableview.allowsMultipleSelection = true

        if AppDelegate.debug {
            print("HistoryViewLoaded")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        tableview.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return data.getMatchDataCount()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! HistoryViewTableCell

        if !AppDelegate.device.isEqual(to: 4.0) {
             cell.textLabel?.text = "Entry " + (indexPath.item + 1).description
        }

        if data.getMatchDataCount() > 0 {
            cell.matchNumb?.text = data.getMatchTest(matchNumber: indexPath.item)[1].description
            cell.teamNumb?.text = data.getMatchTest(matchNumber:indexPath.item)[0].description
        }

        return cell
    }
}

class HistoryViewTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var teamNumb: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var matchNumb: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var matchPoints: UILabel!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to print the frame of teamNumb & matchNumb, according to the picture it looks like the label is here but has some layout issue.

```
print(matchNumb.frame)
print(teamNumb.frame)
```

And did you code works in Swift 2.2, Swift 2.3 or before?

I had a similar issue, my cell doesn't animate in 'cellForRowAt' function since I convert my project to Swift 3, and I dispatch to main fixed it.
Thought when I debug, this line is already in main thread.

I guess you can try:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Set cell.numb.text here..
}
```

Comment: I actually found out that, in Swift 3 and Xcode 8, the Table Title was causing the issue. I'm not entirely sure why it only was occurring during runtime and never appeared during actual editing but I have since avoided using the Table Title for the current configuration (iOS 10, Swift 3, and Xcode 8).